# How to get function name in javascript arrow function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to get a function's name in an arrow function

Actually, if we write

```
function abc(){
  let funcName = arguments.callee.name
}
```

But in an arrow function

```
abc: ()=>{
  let funcName = arguments.callee.name
}
```

funcName return ''

Comment: Isn't it an anonymous function ?

Comment: This is kind of like asking what is the variable name of the number `12`

Comment: @MaxZoom I have added function name

Comment: Are you sure you don't get an [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#no_binding_of_arguments) when you access `arguments` object inside the arrow function?

Comment: Your second `abc:` example is a property named `abc` that contains a pointer to an arrow function.  The function itself has no idea what property it is assigned to.  That's like asking what property any value is assigned to.  The value has no idea. In fact, it could be assigned to many different properties, all with different names.

Comment: The name of the function is "abc:", assigned to the arrow function when it was compiled as the `abc` property of a parent object. You could just hard code it in the arrow function if you want.

Comment: Please make your second example valid JS, completing it with the full object literal code and showing how you are calling the function.

Answer (score 8):

- Arrow functions do not have an `arguments` binding. But they have access to the arguments object of the closest non-arrow parent function. Named and rest parameters are heavily relied upon to capture the arguments passed to arrow functions.

```js
function dummy() {
  return (() => arguments.callee.name)(); // dummy
}
```

- The value of `this` inside an arrow function remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is bound to the value of the closest `this`-providing environment.

```js
const obj = {
  // like a normal function, returns obj - defines like obj.a = function a() {};
  a() { return this },
  // arrow function uses global as this
  b: () => { return this },
};
console.log(obj.a() == obj) // true
console.log(obj.b() == obj) // false
console.log(obj.b() == window) // true
```

- Arrow functions can never be used as constructor functions. Hence, they can never be invoked with the new keyword. As such, a prototype property does not exist for an arrow function.

Therefor, the only way to get the name of an arrow function is from accessing the direct reference to it.

```js
const arrow = () => arrow.name;
console.log(arrow()); // "arrow"

const obj = {
  a: () => obj.a.name;
}
console.log(obj.a()); // "a"
```

Comment: Other than "*your code code does not work (because arrow functions have no `arguments`)*", I don't see how this answers the question about getting the `.name`

Comment: *"is always bound to the value of `this` in the closest non-arrow parent function."* Probably good enough for most use cases but just for completeness: It's the closest "`this`-providing" environment, which can be the global environment or a module environment (not that those `this` values would be very interesting, but still).